# Wordpress + REST API v2 and private pages Load by slug

Tags: rest-api, authentication

Im creating WP theme based on VUE, anyway I load pages based on slug - no by ID.
I use base **X-WP-Nonce** header authentication, it working well with revision etc.

So now I have a **private page** and my return from `wp-json/v2/pages?slug=privatepage` is equal to empty array like it cant find this page. 
But when I created a custom request that load this page by **ID** `wp-json/v2/pages/105 - (private page ID)` it is fine, it return page. When I make page non private, load by slug working correctly. (Im using GET call)

Is there any known way to make WP REST return private pages using slug? Or it is some kind of bug ?

Comment: Maybe it could be done using the `filter[name]=slug` as it is suggested here: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/456

Comment: Ok thanks, but Im using Wordpress json api v2 without wp-rest plugin. Or it is just impossible, and I MUST use this plugin to load private pages by slug?

Comment: Well actually it is just a suggestion, maybe you should try to write a filter in order to pass the argument to the query even if it is a private page, or writing a custom endpoint to handle your use case would be even easier. Having a reproducible example of your code and environment would be easier to help you.

Comment: Actually this is my repo with my base Vue theme for WP https://github.com/isuke01/Wordpress-Vue-Theme
It is simply to setup. App.js contain small debug tool to load page by ID or by slug. Obviously to try private pages, you have to use build version, because you're not logged in in dev localhost :)

Comment: I can't find App.js file :$

Comment: Sorry, App.vue, in SRC directory
https://github.com/isuke01/Wordpress-Vue-Theme/blob/master/src/App.vue